# Use of uninitialized value $2 in concatenation (.) or string

Tags: perl

I transferred my site on another server and this error happened :

PERL : 
Use of uninitialized value $2 in concatenation (.) or string at /Toolbox.pm line 40.

The function :

```
36 sub WT_filter{
37 
38    my $filter = sub {
39         my $text_ref = shift;
40         $$text_ref =~ s/\[\%([^ ]+?)( .*)?\%\]/<TMPL_VAR NAME=\"$1\"$2>/g;
41    };
42
43    return $filter;
44
45 } #sub WT_filter
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the regex `/\[\%([^ ]+?)( .*)?\%\]/`. Or written more readable:

```
/
  \[\%
  ( [^ ]+? )  # $1
  ( [ ].* )?    # $2
  \%\]
/x
```

You might notice that the `$2`-group is completely optional. If the pattern for `$2` doesn't match, it will be set to `undef`. It does not match if there isn't at least one space between the variable name and the closing `%]`: `[%foo-bar%]`.

Possible solutions include:

- changing the pattern for `$2` so that it also accepts zero-length strings: `( .* )`
- using a default value for `$2` before interpolating:

  ```
  s{\[\%([^ ]+?)( .*)?\%\]}{qq[<TMPL_VAR NAME="$1"] . ($2 // q[]) . q[>]}eg
  ```

  (will only work from perl 5.10 onwards)
- switch off this warning in the scope of the filter: `no warnings'uninitialized';`.

Note that your substitution mechanism is susceptible to XML injection, and will have problems when a variable `[% … %]` block is stretched over multiple lines, or when two variables are on the same line. Assuming `escape()` escapes some data for safe use in XML, then the following should work:

```
s{
  \[%
  (\S+?)  # $1 is a sequence of non-space characters
  (?: \s+ ["]([^"]+)["] )?  # $2 is anything inside double quotes
  %\]
}{
  (defined $2)
  ? (sprintf q[<TMPL_VAR NAME="%s" "%s">], escape($1), escape($2))
  : (sprintf q[<TMPL_VAR NAME="%s">], escape($1))
}gsex
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! Robby had also the same answer but yours was more complete.

Comment: Agreed. +1 from me too for the `//` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your regular expression:

```
\[\%([^ ]+?)( .*)?\%\]
```

You're trying to extract two groups: `([^ ]+?)` and `( .*)?`. Note that the second group is followed by a question mark (`?`), marking it as optional.

Now, let's say you try to match text in which the second optional group is not present, for example `[%whatever%]`

In this case, the second backreference variable (`$2`) will not be initialized. If you then try to use that uninitialized variable in your replace expression (`<TMPL_VAR NAME=\"$1\"$2>`), you'll get the error you mention in your question.

To fix the issue, change your regular expression if possible, or you could create a small scope that temporarily disables the warning:

```
my $filter = sub {
    my $text_ref = shift;
    {
        no warnings qw/uninitialized/;
        $$text_ref =~ s/\[\%([^ ]+?)( .*)?\%\]/<TMPL_VAR NAME=\"$1\"$2>/g;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The regexp's second parenthesis did not match anything.

It seems that the functions rewrites e.g.:
`[%something other params%]`
to:
`<TMPL_VAR_NAME="something" other params>`

It seems that the string must have looked like this:
`[%something%]`, which matched only `([^ ]+?)` but not `( .*)`.

Take a look in the file in which this error occurred, you should be able to find the troublesome string.